# "Duration" of elements on a Propel Instance Pool

Tags: php, propel

I'm new in PHP, and also in Propel.

As I have read, Propel got a Instance Pool, to reuse querys.

For example

```
    <?php
// first call
$author1 = AuthorQuery::create()->getByFooField('foo');
$foo = $author1->getId();
// SELECT query
...
// second call
$author2 = AuthorQuery::create()->getByFooField('Foo');
// Skips the SQL query and returns the existing $author1 object
$foo = $author2->getId();
```

the thing is

for how many time this objects are alive?
This is origined because I have to parse an excel, and build some objects to persist them in the db.

So, maybe in the excel I read in 100 rows, I read 25 times 'foo', so, querying the db every time for getting the PK will be bad thing, if I can avoid 24 querys.

Looks like Instance Propel solves this problem, but I don't know for how many time.

That depends on time, memory used, or something like the scope where the querys are executed ? (I mean, maybe after the method that executes the first query, the Instance Pool is cleared, so, unless the second query is in the same method, it will query again the db. Or maybe while the object is alive, I don't know)

I've search a little but not found anything, mi intuition tell me that depends on memory used, but, nothing official.

Or maybe there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: I don't think the instance pool works on queries, but rather on relations. In other words, the first time you do `$author->getBooks()` Propel executes a query, the next time it looks at the `books` collection on that `Author` and sees it is already filled, so no query is executed. If you go through the `*Query` objects, I think it always does a query.

Comment: that's not what I think, reading this http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#propel-instance-pool (there's where I got the example)

Comment: Note that those examples always use a query with the primary `Id` field. The instance pool is simply a mapping of class/table and `Id` value. Doing a find on an arbitrary field - `Foo` in your case - cannot be cached in the instance pool because Propel doesn't know that those are all of the records with that value for the `Foo` field.

Comment: if the foo field is unique, how that changes? not necesary a PK, if not a unique key

Comment: I understand what you are thinking, but I'm just telling you how Propel works. It does not cache queries, it caches instances by `Id`. Any time you do a `->find()` (or most of it's variants) Propel WILL make a call to the database. If on the other hand you request a record by primary key (and nothing else) then Propel will check the instance pool first. (I'll add an answer to this effect as I have checked the code myself now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding an answer that follows my comments above.

Basically, the instance pool is a collection of objects organized by primary key. It is **not** a cache of queries, but rather one of specific instances. Just about any time you request a specific record it will be added to the instance pool for that class. When you then request that record by it's primary key a second time, Propel will give you back the cached object instead of hitting the database. Any time you issue a `->find()` Propel **will** hit the database, regardless of the instance pool.

In your generated base classes you can see this behavior by looking for the `findPk` method and seeing how it uses `getInstanceFromPool()` and `addInstanceToPool()`.

For example:

```
$entity1 = EntityQuery::create()->findPk(13); // WILL hit database
$entity2 = EntityQuery::create()->findPk(13); // WILL NOT hit database

// This WILL hit DB, even if there is only 1 record & it is in the instance pool
$entity3 = EntityQuery::create()->findOneByName("Record Thirteen");
// This will also hit the DB EVERY TIME, regardless of the instance pool
// even though it is the same query
$entity4 = EntityQuery::create()->findOneByName("Record Thirteen");

// This will always hit the database, even if the instance is in the pool
$entity5 = EntityQuery::create()->findByUniqueField("Unique Value");
```

Hope this helps. Again, this is not speculation, I have gone into the code and double checked this. You can look in your generated base classes and in `propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php` (specifically the `find()` method) to see how it works.